# SQSListener not getting triggered

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs

I have a basic spring boot app that tries to listen to SQS messages via `@SQSListener`.

Below are the dependencies :

```
 implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:3.1.0")

 implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging:2.2.6.RELEASE")
 implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.1.0")
```

Below is the service class with the listener :

```
@Service
public class QueueListenerService {

    @SqsListener(value = "test-queue", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
    public void receiveMessage(String message){
        System.out.println("Received message : " + message);
    }
}
```

The application comes up successfully and there’s no error however the listener won’t get invoked at all! Any thoughts on what could be going wrong

Comment: Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77299060/my-sqslistener-is-not-listening-the-queue).