# My @Sqslistener is not listening the queue

Tags: java, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-aws

I am using the @SqsListener annotation of spring cloud aws, however it is not listening to the queue as I send messages and it does not process them.

this is the method:

```
@SqsListener(queueNames = {"fooQueue.fifo"})
public void loadMessagings(String message) {
    System.out.println("mensaje: " + message);
}
```

i have seen in some stack overflow that the reason may be the version of dependencies, but my dependencies are correctly acording https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws

these are my dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
---
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    <aws.java.sdk.version>2.21.0</aws.java.sdk.version>
    <slf4jVersion>1.6.1</slf4jVersion>
</properties>
---
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-sqs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
---
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

there are some idea? i'm facing this issue for couple days

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. I placed a breakpoint inside `AbstractSqsMessageSource:doPollForMessages` inside the `spring-cloud-aws-sqs` library (I'm using version 3.0.3) and I was able to see that the SDK is actually polling from the right set of queues but doesn't get any messages even though I have several messages in the queues. I'm using [`localstack`](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/aws/sqs/) to mimick the SQS queue.